# How to prevent restarting a running Service - Android

Tags: java, android

i'm want to do long background work
also i want to be able to show progress with statistics in ui anytime user goes to a activity also with updating notification.

i start a Service in START_STICKY mode then i bind it to my activity and run the proccess with an public method of Service.

everything works well until i close my app from recent apps.

it destroys and restart my running Service.

that's the problem. "i don't want my running service to restart"

i want my service to keep running without termination and without restarting.

how can i do what i want to do?

why os restart a running service: / thou

i tried START_NOT_STICKY but it's closing the service too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android 6+, a foreground service will not be stopped when the user removes the app from recents.  You can make your service a foreground service by adding this code to `onCreate()`:

```
final Intent launcherIntent = new Intent();
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, launcherIntent, 0);
final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Test Notification")
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
final Notification notification;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    notification = builder.build();
}
else {
    //noinspection deprecation
    notification = builder.getNotification();
}
this.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Prior to Android 6, services are always killed when the user removes the task from recents.  There is nothing you can do about it except shut down cleanly in `onTaskRemoved()`.

Comment: sorry i'm confused. u mean i kill the service before user close app? what do i do now?

Comment: @Mehrad I gathered from your comments on other posts that you want the service to stop and not be restarted when the user removes the app from recents.  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: you misunderstood. i want my service to keep running without termination of current service and without restarting service. when user close app

Comment: @Mehrad Sorry.  Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. but how music players don't stop when u close the app?

Comment: @Mehrad Can you give an example of one that doesn't?  I use Pandora, and it politely stops its service when you swipe it from recents, even on 6+.

Comment: Samsung music player with api 23  also mxplayer in api 19+ and  Sony music player with api 19 ( not sure for sony)

Comment: @Mehrad I think I was wrong about when the change occurred.  Maybe it was between Android 5.0 and 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try using foreground service:

In method where you start service:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
startService(startIntent);
```

Now in `onStartCommand()`:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Read more [Simple foreground service](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/simple-android-foreground-service-example/)

OR you can try something like this:

from `onStartCommand()` need to return `START_STICKY`

override in your service `onDestroy` method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("broadcast.Message", "alarm, need to restart service");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

Now need to implement broadcast receiver:

```
public class RestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service Stops! Oooooooooooooppppssssss!!!!");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check if service is running or not 

if(!isBackgroundServiceRunning(BackgroundServices.class))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,BackgroundServices.class);
            startService(intent);
        }

private boolean isBackgroundServiceRunning(Class<?> service)
    {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)(getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE));

        if (manager != null)
        {
            for(ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo info : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
            {
                if(service.getName().equals(info.service.getClassName()))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```